# Find macOS App Store applications that were installed by another Apple ID

Tags: macos, mac-app-store, apple-id

I have a Macbook Pro which I started using for work with my work Apple ID but now I'm using it privately entirely and I don't have access to the Apple ID I used for work.

Now there are updates for a bunch of applications that I installed using my work Apple ID and I can't update them since I can't log in with that account anymore. Is there any way to find *all* applications that were installed using the old work Apple ID so that I can remove them and install them with my private Apple ID?

Comment: afaik, there's no real mechanism to do that, short of looking down your own Purchased list in App Store.app & checking which are missing.